# R JSONlite: How to tackle below error?

Tags: r, web-scraping, jsonlite

*See the below R code, I'm using JSONlite package to scrape data from a website:*

```
library(jsonlite)
    url <- "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/"
    seasonsdata <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=20))
    seasonsdata <- seasonsdata[-1,]
    fetchData <- function(i) {res <- try(a <- fromJSON(paste0(url,i)))
    if(!inherits(res,"try-error")) {b<-data.frame(a[1],a[20],a[21],as.data.frame(a$season_history))}}

    seasonsdata <- lapply(1:696, fetchData)
    seasonsdata <-do.call(rbind,lapply(seasonsdata,data.frame,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

*The code is working fine for 'i' till 10 at least, I'm getting the desired output. However, as I increase 'i' to 696, I'm getting the error:*

```
Error in data.frame(a[1], a[20], a[21], as.data.frame(a$season_history)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

*Any advise?*

Comment: Check the number of rows in `a[1]`, `a[20]`, `a[21]`, and `as.data.frame(a$seasonhistory)`.  They need to be the same to create the data frame.  Looks like you may need to add a line of code to insert `NA`s where necessary.

Comment: can you help me correct the code?

Answer (score 0):

If `a$season_history` is empty (page 57 is an example) then when you do `data.frame(a[1], a[20], a[21], as.data.frame(a$season_history))` the first 3 elements have one row (they are scalars) and the last element has zero rows. In your function you can first check if `a$season_history` is there. If it it's not you can create a row of `NA`s in its places.

However there is another problem with your code you may not be aware of yet. Not every page to 696 exists and you get a 404 error when you try to pull the data from it. I added some steps to remove those pages before you do the final `do.call(rbind, ...)` step.

```
library(jsonlite)
url <- "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/"
seasonsdata <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 20))
seasonsdata <- seasonsdata[-1, ]
fetchData <- function(i) {
  res <- try(a <- fromJSON(paste0(url, i)))
  if (!inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    if (nrow(as.data.frame(a$season_history)) == 0) {
      b <- data.frame(a[1], a[20], a[21], as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 17)))
    } else {
      b <- data.frame(a[1], a[20], a[21], as.data.frame(a$season_history))
    }
  }
}

seasonsdata <- lapply(1:696, fetchData)
seasonsdata <- seasonsdata[!sapply(seasonsdata, is.null)]
seasonsdata <- seasonsdata[sapply(seasonsdata, is.data.frame)]
seasonsdata <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seasonsdata, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```